# Webpack/grunt-webpack , stop logging on prod build task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webpack

I have a webpack grunt task building my app for me. It's been working great, however I notices my jenkins job logs a huge blob of text from the prod buil (specifically the webpack part), and I'm looking into if i can fix that.

The problem is it logs out this :

```
 ...0% compile 10% 0/1 build modules 70% 1/1 build modules 40% 1/2 build modules 30% 1/3...
```

I cut this short, its around 600 modules, so the text block is gigantic.

From googling around I found something, and tried to add this to my prod webpack file

```
stats: {
       assets: false,
       colors: true,
       modules: false,
       version: false,
       hash: false,
       timings: false,
       chunks: false,
       chunkModules: false
},
```

However, this did not seem to work. I found this thread which seemed to be the right direction https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/476 , however I could not get any of those suggested fixes to work. I am using `grunt-webpack`, and just incase  it may help, here is my `prod` task :

```
return {
    prod: {
        entry: {
            index: './client/app.jsx'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, '../client'),
            publicPath: "/client/",
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        },
        stats: {
            assets: false,
            colors: true,
            modules: false,
            version: false,
            hash: false,
            timings: false,
            chunks: false,
            chunkModules: false
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "process.env": {
                    "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ]
    }

}
```

I am just trying to change it so the prod task doesn't everything, if it just said something like 'build complete' that would be ideal. Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks!